# Регулярное выражение... опять

Tags: регулярные-выражения, url

Всем ДВС!
Есть строка типа:

```
"
<a href="//site.ru/bla/bla">any text</a>
<script src="http://www.site.ru/bla/bla"></script>
<img src="https://any.sub.site.ru/bla/bla">
<a href="https://any.cdn.ru/bla/bla/https://site.ru/img">any text</a>
"
```

Необходимо получить все вхождения домена с поддоменами, но только не в том случае если адрес является частью другого адреса (как в последней строке).
Сам я дошел до выражения:

```
(?<!\/)(https?:)?\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*
```

Но оно возвращает не правильное значение.

Comment: Может так? В первой группе будет результат: `((?<=\/\/)[A-Za-z0-9.-]*)(?!\/\/).*?>`

Comment: Нет. Так возвращаются все адреса целиком.  Необходимо получить из первой строки site.ru, www.site.ru, any.sub.site.ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете JS, то `(?<!\/)(?<!\/\/.+)(https?:)?\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*`.

`(?<!` - это отрицательный lookbehind оператор. Он говорит: "принимай только те выражения перед которыми не стоит то что запрещено". В нашем случае мы принимает только те выражения, перед которыми нет `\/\/.+`.

Lookbehind не во всех языках может быть переменной длины. В случае с JS он может быть переменным, поэтому в нём могут быть символы `+` и `*`.

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

ДВС!

```js
const string = 'https://any.cdn.ru/bla/bla/https://site.ru/img'

console.log(string .match(/(\/\/).+?(\/)/g).map(string => string .replace(/(\/?)/g, '')))
```

Comment: Как раз задача состоит в том, чтобы данный URL в принципе не попал в результат, поскольку искомый домен являются частью адреса другого домена